# Regex to find a group which not match with given pattern?

Tags: java, regex, pattern-matching

I have a string say :
`test=t1,test2=1,test3=t4`

I want to find group or value where test2 value is `not equal to 1`,
I know I can find its value easily by using regex like `.+,test2=(.+?),.+`. but it also give me where `test2=1`, but I want test2 value only if it is not equal to one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [negative lookahead assertion](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html):

```
"test2=(?!1\\b)([^,]*)"
```

Above pattern will match`test2` will match only if it is not followed by `1` (word boundary `\b` is used to not match numbers like `17`, but only match `1`)

Comment: It is not giving me test2 value.

Comment: @user3717431, If you want catch the number for test2: `"test2=(?!1\\b)(\\d+)"` or `"test2=(?!1\\b)([^,]*)"`

Comment: Might be I am not able to make question clear, I am looking value of test2 string only if test2 value is not equal to 1 like test2=1 then it should not return any value but other then that like if test2=12 or test2=T1 it should return test2 corresponding value like 12 or T1

Comment: @user3717431, `"test2=(?!1\\b)([^,]*)"` should work: See https://regex101.com/r/sN8kT8/1

Comment: Yes it work only problem is that regex which you have given is \\b but is Regex tester you have used \b that is why it work but not working for me. thanks.

Comment: @user3717431, You're welcome. I escaped the `\ ` in `\b` because I thought it would be used as a string literal in Java program. Sorry for confusion.

Answer (score 0):

This will work for you :

```
    String s = "test=t1,test2=2,test3=t4";
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("test2=(?!1,)(\\d+)");
    Matcher m = p.matcher(s);
    while (m.find()) {
        System.out.println(m.group(1));
    }
```

I/O :

> "test=t1,test2=2,test3=t4" 
>  2
>
> "test=t1,test2=11,test3=t4" 
>  11
>
> "test=t1,test2=1,test3=t4" 
>  **no result**

Comment: Might be I am not able to make question clear, I am looking value of test2 string only if test2 value is not equal to 1 like test2=1 then it should not return any value but other then that like if test2=12 or test2=T1 it should return test2 corresponding value like 12 or T1

Comment: @user3717431 - Check now